# Creating remote registry with wso2bam

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying out wso2bam-2.4.0 partial distributed cluster and so trying the create remote registry as per instructions.

When the server start, I see "Failed to activate Registry Core bundle" because of

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} -  Failed to close transaction.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of closed connections

I tried these steps on a fresh standalone install (with h2 db) and same error happens when I enable the remote registry with

```
<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
 <id>registryInstance</id>
 <dbConfig>wso2registry</dbConfig>
 <readOnly>false</readOnly>
 <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
 <instanceId>registryInstance</instanceId>
 <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
 <instanceId>registryInstance</instanceId>
 <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Here are snippet of stacktrace that my prove useful

```
[2013-11-13 21:27:18,168]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 1ms
[2013-11-13 21:27:18,490] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} -  Failed to commit transaction.
    java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of committed connections
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.commit(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1227)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.commitTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:159)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.commitTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:452)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:546)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:180)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:524)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.MediaTypesUtils.getResourceMediaTypeMappings(MediaTypesUtils.java:265)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMediaTypes(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:576)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
```

Comment: Just let you know. Same issue exist on wso2bam-2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

(assuming your database is MySQL) Also try and update the number of database connections (as root user)

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections=300;
```